# Return ASP Classic Variable to JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am trying to send some information from a drop down menu when it changes to a classic Asp action page which I want to have grab the information, format it as needed and then return the final variable value.  Everything submits fine to Asp but I get a blank value returned.

Here is my JQuery

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "newslettercreate_action.asp", 
    data: { newsletter_publication: id_val, func_id: "1" },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(theSite) {
    alert(theSite);
},
    error: function(){
    alert("fail");
}
           });
```

And here is the Asp that is handling this information

```
    thisQuery = ""
    set thisRS = dbAccessObj.DirectQuery("live", thisQuery)
    newsletter_list = thisRS("newsletter_list")
    newsletter_list_vals = Split(newsletter_list,"_")
    UBound(newsletter_list_vals)
    theSite = newsletter_list_vals(0)
```

I modded the asp code a bit to just show the important parts.  My ultimate goal is to return theSite to JQuery Ajax to later be used but as I said, it is returning a blank value.

Comment: Have you tried calling that ASP page directly in a browser to make absolutely sure it is returning a value? If you hardcode the newslettercreate_action.asp to response.write a value does that work?

Comment: Also when you say "I get a blank value returned", returned by what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you writing out the value?  I don't see a Response.Write in your posted code:

```
Response.Write(theSite)
```

Comment: I didn't have a response.write.  I thought I would have just needed to define the variable.  This worked out.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are printing a response on the ASP page

```
response.write(some viariable)
```

I had the same issue. On your Ajax code make sure you are set to GET not POST